# Feature geometries sometimes treated as equal, sometimes not (PyQGIS)

Tags: pyqgis, geometry

QGIS 3.4x64 and Python 3.7 seem to sometimes treat my geometries as equal, sometimes not.

I'm debugging code using a reduced dataset with 3 points. Points A and B have the same geometry, and point C is different. I verified this using geometry.isEqual().

I need a dictionary with the format { geometry : [point_ids] }, where the key is the geometry of a point, and the value is a list of all points with that geometry.

When I run the following code, my dictionary should be { geomA : [A, B], geomC : [C] }.

```
reverse_geoms.setdefault(g, list()).append(v)
```

Instead, I get { gA : [A], gB : [B], gC : [C] }.

So this means that I have a duplicate key, because gA == gB. Or, it means the geometries aren't actually equal, but I checked and I believe they are. Is there something wrong with my code, or am I misunderstanding something about geometries?